# Creating setup.py for making .exe

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I am working with python3.4 on windows 7.Using py2exe for making executable file.
In my python script i am opening multiple folders and reading files from them.The setup.py used is as follows,

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os ,difflib

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(

    windows=['script.py'],
      name="XYZ",
      options = {'py2exe': {
        "optimize": 2,
        "bundle_files": 1,
        "compressed": True   
      }},
)
```

The directory which holds the setup file and python script also have folders containing data files. so how can i possibly include the folders within this setup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page in the py2exe wiki should help: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files

Comment: i have to include 3 folders in my setup.py ...the link doesnt tell how to do that....and if i hardcode folder path in setup.py as given in the link i doubt if the exe works on other systems.....